# Clojure core.cache custom cache

Tags: caching, clojure

I am using clojure.core.cache for caching the retrieved values in a webapp. I would like to use a custom cache for this purpose and I am trying to define it as specified here : https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Extending. I am getting the following error :

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defcache in this context, compiling:
```

Can anyone please lead me to an appropriate example/usage pattern?

P.S. : I am pretty new to clojure world

**EDIT** :

I got it to work. I am using Light Table for writing a quick sample program and the issue was that Light Table did not retrieve the `clojure.core.cache` dependency.

Comment: In order to use a function from some library, you need to be sure the dependency is fulfilled (easiest to do this by declaring it in project.clj and developing / building with leiningen) and you need to require it in your namespace (using the :require key in the ns macro - :use is also possible, but :require with an optional alias via :as is better)

Comment: in the repl, you can use require directly rather than via the ns macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the edit to the question already, posting it as answer here.

I got it to work. I am using Light Table for writing a quick sample program and the issue was that Light Table did not retrieve the `clojure.core.cache` dependency.